# Some values are "£x per month and some are £x per week". How can I use Power Query to remove the text and convert the monthly figures into weekly

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-2016

I have a column of figures named "Price".

Some of my data are displayed as "£1000 per month", "£500 per month" and some of them are "£120 per week" or "£250 per week" for example.

I want to convert this column using Power Query into a column that returns the weekly value.

For example, "£250 per week" would return "250" and "£1000 per month" would return (1000/4.34813 - a rough conversion to per week) 229.98.

I am using Excel 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, in powerquery

right click column and replace values **per week** with **/1**

right click column and replace values **per month** with **/4.34813**

Add column, custom column with

```
= Expression.Evaluate(Text.Select([OriginalColumnNameHere],{"0".."9",".","/"}))
```

That will evaluate the text **€1000/4.34** and return 230.41

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"per week","/1",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1"}),
#"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","per month","/4.34",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value1", "Custom", each Expression.Evaluate(Text.Select([Column1],{"0".."9",".","/"})))
in  #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: The reason I am using 4.34 as it is comparing some suppliers who charge monthly and some who charge weekly. Weekly is the amount many of my other comparisons use, so it is good to standardise based on that 4.34 is rough but it is good enough for the level of precision I need here.